# Reactjs, call a function in another method with ref, Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference, react-redux

I have two components let say A, B and both are connected to Redux store. 
in B I have a function that controls its local state. but from A I want to access it.

```
 class A extends React.Component{ 
  funcInA=()=>{this.Balt.funcInB();}
  render(){return(
   <B ref={Balt => {this.Balt= Balt;}} />
   <button onClick={this.funcA}
);}}
export default connect (null,null,null,{withRef:true})(A)
```

and the B component is like

```
 class B extends React.Component{ 
  state={a:''}
  funcInB=()=>{this.setState({a:'text'})}
  render(){return(...);}}
export default connect (null,null,null,{withRef:true})(B)
```

but here I get `Uncaught TypeError: _this.Balt.funcInB is not a function`

Comment: @NicholasTower Using the life cycle hooks are so risky. at least I usually mess it up. so there is no way to call a method in another method?

Comment: You *can* call methods in other methods, you're just not going about it the right way here.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox.io for you example?